# Removing class from TD cell based on TR ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to remove a class name from a TD cell using the parent TR id.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<tr class="text-nowrap" id="abc0003212" role="row">
    <td class="move-icon white-font sorting_1">2</td>
    <td class="">3</td>
</tr>
```

My most recent attempt with jquery looks like tjhis:

```
...
var record = 'abc0003212';
$('#'+record).closest('white-font').remove();
...
```

Any thoughts why this isn't working?

Thanks,

Comment: `closest()` goes up, not down. Use `find()` or `children()`.

Comment: use `.find('.white-font')` instead of `.closest`

Comment: .. and you're missing the `.` in the selector (should be `.white-font`)

Comment: ahh...I didn't realize that.  What's the equivalent for searching down?

Comment: `$('#' + record).find('.white-font').remove();`

Comment: `$('#'+record).find('.white-font').removeClass('white-font');`

Comment: if u want to remove only class name use  .removeClass('yourclass');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#' + record + ' .white-font').removeClass('white-font')
```

since you do not want to remove the Element but just the class.

Answer (score 1):

`closest` will look for the closest ancestor, not descendant.  Use `find`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$('#' + record + ' .white-font').removeClass('white-font');
```

Comment: That will remove the element, not the class name. The question asks to remove class name.

Comment: Yup, just noticed that - amended answer

Answer (score 1):

Two issues.  First, as others have pointed out `closest` goes up the dom not down.  Second, you can be more specific in your search.

I would try something like:

```
$('#' + record + ' td.white-font').removeClass('white-font');
```

That will limit it to only `TD` that have the class `white-font`.

Comment: you could simplify this as `$('#' + record + ' td.white-font').removeClass('white-font')`